# why any three points in four cannot be collinear when solving a 2-dimensional projective transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projective-geometry

Suppose map a 2-dimensional point $(x,y)$ to its image point $(x',y')$ by a projective transformation $H$. So we derive that
$$x'(h_{31}x+h_{32}y+h_{33})=h_{11}x+h_{12}y+h_{13}$$
$$y'(h_{31}x+h_{32}y+h_{33})=h_{21}x+h_{22}y+h_{23}$$
  So a point correspondence lead to two linear equations which are linear in the elements in $H$. Now suppose there are 4 point correspondences:
$$(x^{(1)},y^{(1)}) \leftrightarrow (x'^{(1)},y'^{(1)}) $$
$$(x^{(2)},y^{(2)}) \leftrightarrow (x'^{(2)},y'^{(2)}) $$
$$(x^{(3)},y^{(3)}) \leftrightarrow (x'^{(3)},y'^{(3)}) $$
$$(x^{(4)},y^{(4)}) \leftrightarrow (x'^{(4)},y'^{(4)}) $$
From above 4 point correspondences we derive 8 equations about elements of $H$, and write it in matrix form:
$$\begin{bmatrix} x^{(1)} & y^{(1)} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & x^{(1)}x'^{(1)} & y^{(1)}x'^{(1)} & x'^{(1)} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & x^{(1)} & y^{(1)} & 1 &x^{(1)}y'^{(1)} & y^{(1)}y'^{(1)} & y'^{(1)} \\
x^{(2)} & y^{(2)} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & x^{(2)}x'^{(2)} & y^{(2)}x'^{(2)} & x'^{(2)} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & x^{(2)} & y^{(2)} & 1 &x^{(2)}y'^{(2)} & y^{(2)}y'^{(2)} & y'^{(2)} \\
x^{(3)} & y^{(3)} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & x^{(3)}x'^{(3)} & y^{(3)}x'^{(3)} & x'^{(3)} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & x^{(3)} & y^{(3)} & 1 &x^{(3)}y'^{(3)} & y^{(3)}y'^{(3)} & y'^{(3)} \\
x^{(4)} & y^{(4)} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & x^{(4)}x'^{(4)} & y^{(4)}x'^{(4)} & x'^{(4)} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & x^{(4)} & y^{(4)} & 1 &x^{(4)}y'^{(4)} & y^{(4)}y'^{(4)} & y'^{(4)} \\
\end{bmatrix}    \begin{bmatrix} h_{11} \\ h_{12} \\ h_{13} \\ h_{21} \\ h_{22} \\ h_{23} \\ h_{31} \\ h_{32} \\ h_{33} \\\end{bmatrix}=0$$
 Denoting above system as $A \mathbf h=0$ where $A \in R^{8 \times 9} $ and $\mathbf h \in R^9$.

To my understanding, dimension of A's nullspace:
$$dim(N(A))=9-Rank(A) \ge 1 $$ because $Rank(A) \le 8$. So there must exist a nonzero solution to system $A \mathbf h=0$.

**My question**: why qualify that three points cannot be collinear?

Original problem comes from R.Hartley & A.Zisserman [*Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision*](http://cvrs.whu.edu.cn/downloads/ebooks/Multiple%20View%20Geometry%20in%20Computer%20Vision%20(Second%20Edition).pdf) at page 35:[image: depictions]

Comment: I haven't read the proof here, but as long as you're going to send those three collinear points to three other collinear points, it should be fine. Your matrix will have lower rank, but you're still specifying a vector in its image (column space).

Comment: Read ahead: They cover what goes wrong in section 4.1.3.